# Why is Entity Framework .ToList() with .Include very slow and how can I speed it up?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am querying an oracle database with EF4.

I have 2 to tables `POINTS` (with around 100 000 rows) and `COUNTRIES`, each point having a `countryCode` as foreign key

I have the 2 below methods in a repository

```
public List<PointsTable> GetAll()
{
    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        List<PointsTable> theList = context.POINTS_TABLE.ToList();
        return theList;
    }
}

public List<PointsTable> GetAllComplete()
{
    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        List<PointsTable> theList = context.POINTS_TABLE.Include("Countries").ToList();
        return theList;
    }
}
```

The `GetAll` takes 5 seconds but the `GetAllComplete` takes 2 minutes!

I have using `AsParallel()` but the gain is ridiculous.

Can i speed this up, or whats causing it to be slow?

Comment: GetAllComplete is making join with Countries table and fetching all points and countries, when GetAll is just getting all points without referenced tables. GetAllComplete is getting MUCH more rows. Fetching all items with ToList() is not a good idea when operating on big data.

Comment: But i'm completely lost here, if I run  this in PL/SQL i have no difference between the 2 below queries:
`select * from POINTS_TABLE` and
`select * from POINTS_TABLE a left join COUNTRY_TABLE b on B.CountryCode = A.CountryCode`

Comment: it's EF not sql, ORM's are much slower than sql clients, if you really need to fetch 200k rows at once, use ado.net not EF. But I would rather use linq and fetch row by row, or in 100 points packs.

Comment: @wudzik on your explanation of GetAll "is just getting all points without referenced tables" but i can see all the graph during debug with quick watches. So is it because of debugging feature to traverse through its entire graph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is  that for each record you are retrieving it's countries which for 200k records multiplies into **alot** of records.

Are you going to querying this data later to reduce it to your specific needs? If so don't `.ToList()` them just yet.

Change your repository methods to return `IQueryable`, that way you can restrict the query to the particular data you require later down the line reducing the ammount of data you put into memeory

```
private Entities _context;

public PointsRepository(Entities context)
{
    _context = context
}

public IQueryable<PointsTable> GetAll()
{
    return context.POINTS_TABLE;
}

public IQueryable<PointsTable> GetAllComplete()
{
    return context.POINTS_TABLE.Include("Countries");
}
```

You can then add your specific filters and `ToList` the smaller result. e.g.

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
{
    var rep = new PointsRepository(context);

    // This will change the query you send to sql to only 
    // retrieve the specific data you want and should result 
    // in much quicker execution
    var result = rep.GetAllComplete()                    // get all with includes
                    .Where(p => p.Property = "Specific") // refine the query 
                    .ToList()                            // retrieve the data and add to memory
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

AS Parallel(), not working with Linq to Entities, working only with Linq to Object.

Load 200K with EF not is good plain.

You can improve performance with the readonly load:

```
context.POINTS_TABLE.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```